# express router returns 404 on post method for one url

Tags: javascript, node.js, express, express-router

I have an express app to handle user authentication. My app.js file has `app.use("/", indexRouter);
app.use("/signup", signupRouter);
app.use("/login", indexRouter);`
the `signupRouter` works perfect other than when I check if sign up successful and if not re render the `signup` page. Basically the css goes missing.

```js
router.get("/", function(req, res) {
  res.render("signup", { message: "Fill out the form" });
});

router.post("/register", function(req, res) {
  db.createUser(email, name, password)
    .then(function() {
      res.redirect("/");
    })
    .catch(function(err) {
      console.log("something went wrong");
      res.render("signup", { message: `something went wrong ${err}` }); 
// here css goes missing even though my public folder is set to static.
    });
});
```

I have an `indexRouter` that is:

```
router.get("/", function(req, res) {
  res.render("login", { message: "Enter Credentials" });
});
router.post("/login", function(req, res) {
  db.findUser(email.password)
    .then(function() {
      res.redirect("/dashboard");
    })
    .catch(function(err) {
      res.render("login", { message: "USER/PASSWORD NOT FOUND" });
    });
});
```

Upon hitting this `/login` I get 500/400 errors. How come? My setup for both routers are identical.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looks like some syntax error.
In the `indexRouter` at line db.findUser(email.password), `email.password` seems the culprit.

Shouldn't it be db.findUser(email, password)

Comment: yes. My god I missed it. But what about the css issue. Thanks though.

Comment: For that, need to see the UI code how you are trying to import the css. If it is through link tag, then we need to see if the link is getting removed or if any other the component importing the css has some issues

Comment: yes link tags. It is very weird because for the first case at /register it loads fine. But for the next case when I try to render, it's gone. Any other component as in? because for login section it works fine.

Comment: When you try to render next case (missing css one), is the link tag for css present in your index.html? basically want to know if link tag goes missing or link tag is there but css is not getting applied

Comment: yes they are present. It is probably something to do with static file setup but even that does not make sense.